# is there any springboot integrated Playwright framework available with BDD implementation

Tags: spring-boot, selenium-webdriver, gradle, bdd, playwright-java

We need to migrate our automated tests from selenium-java to playwright-java but needs to have power of `springboot` ,`BDD` features using playwright library.

I referred some of the courses on Udemy but could not find any suitable course which has these three features integrated:

1. use of springboot annotations to avoid boilerplate automation code
2. playwright libraries
3. BDD features
4. gradle build

Comment: why not use cucumber with spring? Instead of selenium plugin playwright to drive the browser.